# Duplicate FrameworkReference for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App

Tags: wpf, .net-core, duplicates, system.reactive, assembly-references

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WPF application that uses System.Reactive version 4.4.1. It builds and works successfully but gives the following warning after building:
"*A FrameworkReference for 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was included in the project. This is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you do not typically need to reference it from your project.* "
How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` on your csproj?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `System.Reactive`. What else do you have referenced?

Comment: What occurances of `<FrameworkReference` do you find if you search through your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. It appears to be an issue with the System.Reactive library which has been resolved but not yet deployed: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/pull/1250

We will wait and see after the next release.

Comment: This has been resolved in version 5 of the library.